# What is meant with this definition of 'Collaboration'

Tags: oop, object

[Object Thinking (by David West)](http://davewest.us/product/object-thinking/) defines *Collaboration* as:

> 1. Object `A` receives a request for one of its advertised services
> 2. While in the process of satisfying that request, it needs to ask for a service from object `B`
> 3. Object `B` is *not*
>
>    1. an object occupying one of object `A`'s instance variables
>    2. a temporary variable declared in the method that object `A` is executing in order to satisfy the original request
>    3. an object supplied to object `A` as an argument of the message requesting the service
>
> Object  `B` becomes the *collaborator*, a covert assistant to object `A`.

However, I have difficulties imagining such an object `B`.

In the below code fragment, neither `helper1`, `helper2` or `helper3` would match the above definition, would it? 
I also suppose that it is not meant to be a call to a *static* method of `B`.

```
class A {

    B helper1 = new B();

    void service(B helper3) {

        B helper2 = new B();

        helper1.service();
        helper2.service();
        helper3.service();

    }

}
```

Anyone that can give me an example of how this definition would look like in practice?

Comment: So the book author defined a _collaborator object_ by saying what its not? No additional information?

Comment: Is there a reason you think the author didn't mean _static_? Because having `B` as Singleton (but getting the instance will be using _static_) can be suitable example.

Comment: No, no explicit example of what it _is_. Based on information in book, I would have thought that my `helper1` and `helper2` were collaborators. That's why the definition confuses me.

Comment: I think the author didn't mean a static method call, like `B.staticService()` because IMO this wouldn't be in line with the philosophy stated in the book. Having `B` defined as a singleton would IMO opinion be equivalent to my `helper2`, i.e. a _temporary variable_. `B.getInstance().service()` is equivalent to `B helper2 = B.getInstance(); B.service()`.

Answer (score 0):

Having read the section in the Object Thinking book, I think an example of this would be as follows:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    Service service;

    public ObjectA(Service service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void ProvideService()
    {
        ObjectB objectB = this.service.DoSomething();
        objectB.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public ObjectB DoSomething()
    {
        ...
        return objectB;
    }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here, `ObjectB` is a collaborator.

In the book, the author mentions that this fits in with the Law of Demeter. The Law of Demeter states that method `ProvideService` of class `ObjectA` should only call the methods of the following:

- `ObjectA` itself
- An object created by `ProvideService`
- An object passed as an argument to `ProvideService`
- An object held in an instance variable of `ObjectA`

`ObjectB` is none of the above and can therefore be classed as a collaborator.

The above method `ProvideService` is a violation of the Law of Demeter and, as the author mentions, this type of collaboration should be kept to a minimum. Often this leads to train wreck code like the following:

```
public void ProvideService()
{
    this.service.DoSomething().DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not convinced that this is what is meant (I'm also not saying that this is _not_ what is meant, because I don't know). I'm not convinced because as I see it,`objectB` is _a temporary variable declared in the method that object A is executing in order to satisfy the original request_.

Comment: @Ward I think to make sense of this we need to interpret "temporary variable declared in the method" as "temporary object created by the method". The example above is the only way, I believe, that ObjectA and ObjectB can directly interact that isn't one of the ways stated by the Law of Demeter, i.e. it is an interaction via a reference or pointer to an object created elsewhere. It's a shame the author didn't include any examples as this would have made it so much clearer. Unfortunately, because of this, we have to use some educated guesswork.

Comment: @Ward In addition, the author also mentions that "it is not an object currently residing inside ObjectA's encapsulation barrier" which would also fit the code example above.